# Video is not filling ExoPlayer view when VideoSize is changed in a playlist [Amazon Fire Stick]

Tags: android, android-tv, exoplayer2.x

I'm using ExoPlayer *(v2.16.1)* building a media player android TV app, however, if there is a playlist of several videos with different resolutions I see a weird behaviour on the display explained below.
**Only Happens on Amazon FireStick (FireOs 6 & 7), works good on other Android TVs**

- All Videos have 16:9 ratio
- Some Videos have resolution of `1920x1080` and others are `960x540`
- When ExoPlayer starts to play the playlist seems it locks the player view to the first frame size which is `1920x1080` for instance.
- So, When a smaller video with `960x540` resolution is played, it occupies only a part of the screen and the last frame of the previous video is still filling the rest of the screen as shown in the following image.
  [image: ExoPlayer Video Size Issue]

Is there any way to make ExoPlayer adaptive to dynamic video sizes?

Comment: Hello. Did you manage to fix this problem?

I'm getting something similar, but when changing resolution of the track in the HLS stream. 

Do you have any updates in this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `app:resize_mode="fill"` in you `PlayerView`

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:resize_mode="zoom"/>
```

Comment: it's not about that, the player  view already is filling the display, but the video itself is not filling the player view. The rest of the player view is filled with the last frame of the previous video.

Comment: Can you try `zoom` and tell if it works or not? I updated my answer too

Comment: Tried it, didn't fix it. 
Worth mentioning that weird behaviour only happens on Amazon FireSticks, other Android TVs is working perfectly.

Comment: @AmrBarakat did you got any solution so far, I am having same problem,

Comment: @Ravindra-RaviVerma not yet.

Comment: @AmrBarakat did you ever find a solution here? I am having a semi-similar issue on fireos using exoplayer. About 30 secs into the first video on boot of the app, it scales to double the size of the screen, so only top left corner of the video is shown. Once the player is unmounted and remounted the issue disappears for all videos, until the app is rebooted.

Comment: @AmrBarakat im having the same issue with firestick light and exoplayer i get like 70% of the video on a fullscreen

Comment: I didn't find a fix here. tho, I have a bit of the control over the video files, so I just ensured that videos have unified resolution.

Answer (score 0):

@Amr Barakat after testing extensibly with all exoplayer versions i found that if the first video in your playlist is low resolution say 720p and the user opens the first frame, even if the next video is 1080p and the third is 720p or even if you go back to the first video in the playlist that is 720p the error will not appear.

But if your first video is 1080p and the next is a low resolution like 720p the error will show up no matter what you do, i tried programatically correcting the video surface and doing lots of tricks, resetting the resolution to exoplayer, doing a scale fill, scale fit, nothing worked.

The lastest version i tried is 2.18.0 as of today. I hope this helps anyone or the exoplayer team find and patch the error.